# Какую библиотеку использовать для создания 3D текста? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, 3d, library, preview

Здраствуйте! Стоит задача генерации 3D текста с помощью JS.
Примеры идеального конечного решения в конвертации текста (статической, без анимации).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Каким образом можно такое реализовать?**
На сколько мне известно, здесь нужен Canvas и JS (библиотека, возможно Three.js) для переобразования текста в 3D формат.

Буду рад, вашим советам и опыту в данной сфере!

**Обновление:**
Не исключена и прямая конвертация в *mockup*, но более оптимизировано по времени.

**Предназначение:**
Функция предназначается для сайта, на котором будет реализована "мини-версия фотошопа" с перемещением элементов на холсте и изменении прессетов цветокорекции.

Comment: можно и на text-shadow запарится - за то без всяких тяжёлых библиотек

Comment: @MaximLensky в "тяжелости" библиотеки нет проблемы. Текст будет генерироваться динамически, поэтому text-shadow - будет иметь слишком скучный вид.

Comment: я уверяю - что конечный результат мало чем будет отличатся ..в настоящее время css3 + прямые руки дают офигенский  результат ..а библиотеки (в 80% случаях) для ленивых хотя ваше дело но не буду настаивать ..есть ещё SVG и так далее

Comment: @MaximLensky вы заверяете, что с помощью CSS3 + text-shadow можно добиться такого же эффекта как на примерах?

Comment: это не та ссылка но как пример показать можно https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/bAzIJ

Comment: https://codepen.io/jeromevanoverbeke/pen/wfzIq  смотрите

Comment: https://codepen.io/hugo/pen/GtHwo  обычный css

Comment: @MaximLensky Большое спасибо за предоставленные примеры. Третий больше всего подходит, по решению через CSS. Вот тоже нашел подобный пример - https://atuin.ru/blog/3d-tekst-na-css/

Но как-то странно, что нет готовых библиотек, для такого вывода.

Comment: @KobetsMatviy если вы хотите свой фотошоп делать, то это canvas, webgl надо изучать, скорее всего